# Cocos2d: is this design pattern valid?

Tags: flash, design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCScene and several CCSprites added as nodes to it. I then have a subclass (also added to the SAME CCScene class instance), which we call here Whatever, of CCSprite that has some clever beheaviour. I'd like to allow this class to reference the CCSprite nodes added to the main scene and modify some properties of them (e.g. visibility). My current solution is to add a pointer to a NSMutableArray as member variable of Whatever class.

I use the CCScene class to trigger those action via the Whatever class. For instance I call the "TriggerAction" method in the Whatever node at specific times. This action modifies the CCSprites belonging to the same parent CCScene.

I am a newbie but it sounds like something potentially dangerous to me and I am wondering if this is a known design pattern or, worse, a known mistake.

Any experience in using a pattern like this? I have added "Flash" as tag as Cocos2D inherits some concepts from Flash.

EDIT:

Whatever is a special sprite (e.g. planet) that when touched is supposed to show LevelIcon sprites. My problem is that I want to position the levelIcons in respect to the planet position on the screen and the easiest way to do so was by adding them to the scene that contained the planets. I will now explore the solution where they are added only to the planet as Whatever sublcasses.. the problem is in this way I couple them a lot and I cannot recycle the Whatever class in other scenes where I don't require the LevelIcons.

[image: Is this pattern valid]

Comment: We'd be able to help you better if we understood specifically what you were attempting to do. Can you give a "real-game" example? The real problem I see with doing what you're doing is that you can't be sure in what order these operations will take place. Therefore, "Whatever's" action's may not "take affect" until the next iteration of updates.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ok pattern but there's the potential for leaking memory since a sibling retains other siblings.

A better solution would be to make the sprites children of the controlling node. That way you don't run the risk of retain cycles, and you don't have to have a separate array to keep references to the sprites since they're already in the children array. You can use tags to identify individual sprites.

If "Whatever" doesn't actually (need to) display anything you should use CCNode as super class instead of CCSprite.

Comment: Whatever is a special sprite (e.g. planet) that when touched is supposed to show LevelIcon sprites. My problem is that I want to position the levelIcons in respect to the planet position on the screen and the easiest way to do so was by adding them to the scene that contained the planets. I will now explore the solution where they are added only to the planet as Whatever sublcasses.. the problem is in this way I couple them a lot and I cannot recycle the Whatever class in other scenes where I don't require the LevelIcons.